# Merge firefox bookmarks

Tags: json, firefox, bookmarks

I have two separate computers on which i have a separate set of bookmarks in firefox.

I want to merge the two so that i have access to all the links at a time.

Is there any utility to help me with this.

I can get the two bookmark files (`.json` - preferred, `.html`) and try to create a single bookmark file by parsing them. But, i want to be sure that there are no errors and i also want to remove duplicates from the resultant file.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Firefox Sync](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sync-take-your-bookmarks-and-tabs-with-you). It is a way to keep your bookmarks, history, preferences, passwords, etc. synced across multiple devices. Also, it comes standard with Firefox; you don't even have to install an Add-on to use it.

Comment: Firefox Sync is an external service subject to it's own policies and privacy terms. Personally I do not recommend. Besides, accepting this as an answer limits the possibilities of actually merging the files, as asked.

Answer (score 2):

Export bookmarks in HTML then import the `bookmarks-date.html` is the simpliest and fastest way to merge a given bookmarks set. 
Especially as Firefox supports export/import *tags* and *annotations* starting with version 43. This allows to export/import any bookmarks' folder(s) you wanna keep, in place of replacing the whole lot, finally :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found the easiest is to download a different version of Firefox  (in my case Firefox Nightly) which I don't use and use it as the host for the new bookmark list.  I exported the bookmarks from both machines in HTML format, naming them differently.  The plugin which I used was - Bookmark Dupes by Martin Väth.

Just import both HTML bookmark files, then use Bookmark Dupes to first delete all duplicates and then delete all empty folders.  You will be then left with a duplicate folder structure which has bookmarks in one but not the other, just move the bookmarks up to one folder and then delete empty folders when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can [export](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer) your bookmarks or just look them up in your [profile folder](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Backing%20up%20your%20information).

I think the easiest way to merge two bookmarks files is importing one profile to the other firefox (and eventually exporting the merged bookmarks again). It does not need any (manual) parsing and should not produce any errors.